Algebraic expression for the geometric group law on the unit circle
A group law can be defined on the unit circle by the following geometric definition

where $N$ is an arbitrary, but fixed point on the circle (which plays the role of the identity element).
Assume that $N=(1, 0)$.  I've read that this group law can be expressed in coordinates algebraically as
$$ P + Q = (x_P x_Q - y_P y_Q, x_P y_Q + x_Q y_P).$$
Presumably there is a straightforward derivation of this fact, but I can't get there!  Any help would be much appreciated.

if $P = ( \cos a, \sin a)$  and $Q = \cos b , \sin b)$  then their $P+Q = (\cos(a+b), \sin(a+b)).$  See what you can do with that

@WillJagy Indeed that would get me there, but it is the premise of that approach (i.e. that the argument/angle of $P+Q$ w.r.t. $N$ is the sum of the arguments of $P$ and $Q$ w.r.t $N$) that I am having trouble proving.

Typo in ur Headline.

This looks like complex number multiplication to me.

.. and the geometric picture visualises exactly that, only by a novel way of "measuring "the angles that are added.

This can be proven in an algebraic manner by simply noting that the equation for the line through $P$ and $Q$ is:
$$ \beta (x - x_P) - \alpha (y - y_P) = 0$$
where $\beta = (y_Q - y_P)$ and $\alpha = (x_Q - x_P)$ are such that $\alpha / \beta$ is the slope of the line.  Since the line through $P+Q$ and $N$ is parallel to this line (and since $N$ is on the line), its equation is:
$$ \beta (x - 1) - \alpha y = 0.$$
It is now easy to check that $(x, y) = (x_P x_Q - y_P y_Q, x_P y_Q + x_Q y_P)$ satisfies both this equation and also the equation of the unit circle.  By Bézout's theorem, at most two points satisfy these equations simultaneously, and so this solution must be $P+Q$.
